# How to set a particular virtual desktop's background using the Terminal or API on macOS 12?

Tags: terminal, desktop, spaces

When I create a new Space on macOS, I set the desktop background to an image associated with the task I will complete in the Space. Something like:

`% set-space-background monitor=1 space=2 ~/backgrounds/streamer-workbench.png`

If there is no off-the-shelf command or application, a pointer to the correct API is also fine for me as I can produce an application from it.

As an example use case: when I am going to stream I create a new desktop, set the background to a photo of a microphone, and populate the Space with my streamer applications.

Previous StackExchange questions addressed similar questions. They and their limitations for me are listed below.

- [How do I change desktop background with a terminal command?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40644/how-do-i-change-desktop-background-with-a-terminal-command) - For an older version of MacOS. Not for changing an individual desktop.
- [How to change desktop wallpaper for all virtual desktops?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71070/how-to-change-desktop-wallpaper-for-all-virtual-desktops/422179#422179) - Not for changing an individual desktop.
- [Setting System Preferences via script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392299/setting-system-preferences-via-script) - Not specific to my situation.